# Perl Syntax: Hash of HashReferences of HashReferences

Tags: perl

I dropped the idea of using this for my program, but I am intrigued because I never found the answer to how to do this. Basically, if I construct something like the following (Please forgive my formatting if the following doesn't appear okay):

- `A = |num_key => hashref_a|`,
- `hashref_a` is a hash reference to `a = |string_keys => hashref_b|`,
- `hashref_b` is a hash reference to `b = |num_key, num_value|`.

So as you see, the first level is a hash with keys being numbers and its values are references to another hash, which in turn is a hash whose keys are strings related to values which are again hash references (these are however hashes of just keys and numbers).

Now, how do I access `b` (the entire list of keys or just the value for a corresponding key) given a `num_key` for the first hash and a particular `string_key` for the second hash.

I really hope I was able to communicate the question clearly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood your request correctly:

```
my %hash = ( num_key => { string_keys => { num_key => 1.234 } } );
```

Or:

```
my %hash_b = ( num_key => 1.234 );
my %hash_a = ( string_keys => \%hash_b );
my %hash_z = ( num_keys => \%hash_a );
```

Hmmm...after editing the question, I think you're asking how to access the values, rather than how to construct them.

```
my $value = $hash{$num_key}->{$string_key}->{num_key};
```

It gets a bit iffy here; I've used `$num_key` but the only valid value for that given the data is 'num_key'; similarly with `$string_key` and 'string_keys'.  The arrows are the key to the notation, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
my %hash = ( 3 => { "hello" => { 18 => 583 } } );

print $hash{3}->{"hello"}->{18};
# ==> 583
```

**EDIT** I see @JonathanLeffler did a pretty much the same answer, but I'll leave mine here as a complement to his, as a runnable demo of his explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
%hash = (
   one => { a => 10, b => 20 },
   two => { c => 30, d => 40 }
);

&function(\%hash);

sub function {
   my $hash = shift;

   $hash->{two}->{d} = 50;   # changes 'd'
}
```

You can go as deep as you want here with hashes of hashes of hashes. Hope that helps...

Comment: You should not use ampersand on function calls unless you know what it does, and what it does is what you want done (it seldom is).